# Compose observe livedata where observeAsState is not the best solution

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata

So I have a ViewModel which posts values into it's LiveData when the hour is being changed (for example, 10:59 -> 11:00).
In my composable I need to observe that LiveData and animate background gradient change on hour change.
Here is how I did that:

```
@Composable
fun GradientForCurrentTime(viewModel: GradientForCurrentTimeViewModel = viewModel()) {
    var gradient by remember {
        val currentHour = Date().hours
        mutableStateOf(listOf(gradients[currentHour][0], gradients[currentHour][1]))
    }

    viewModel.currentHour.observeForever { hour ->
        val previous = gradient
        val new = listOf(gradients[hour][0], gradients[hour][1])

        val evaluator = ArgbEvaluator()

        val animator: ValueAnimator =
            ValueAnimator.ofObject(evaluator, previous[0].toArgb(), new[0].toArgb()).apply {
                addUpdateListener {
                    val newList = listOf(
                        Color(it.animatedValue as Int), Color(
                            evaluator.evaluate(
                                it.animatedFraction,
                                previous[1].toArgb(),
                                new[1].toArgb()
                            ) as Int
                        )
                    )
                    gradient = newList
                }
                duration = 500
            }
        animator.start()

    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                brush = Brush.verticalGradient(gradient)
            )
    )
}
```

And here comes my question:
I need to get rid of `observeForever` because it obviously requires the subscription to cancel, and it is not that easy to do it here.
Also I don't see an optimal way of using `observeAsState`, as I already have the `var gradient by remember`as current state to actually draw gradient.

---

I of course can move the animation calculations into the ViewModel, but should it be an option? Should VeiwModel know anything about animating the view?

Comment: You should be able to use `animateValueAsState`: see https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/package-summary#animateValueAsState(kotlin.Any,androidx.compose.animation.core.TwoWayConverter,androidx.compose.animation.core.AnimationSpec,kotlin.Any,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1)

Comment: @Hack5 looks like a possible solution, will try it now

Comment: @Hack5 it indeed solved my problem. I will post my own answer, but if you wnat to post yourth - please do and I will accept yourth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [animateValueAsState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/package-summary#animateValueAsState(kotlin.Any,androidx.compose.animation.core.TwoWayConverter,androidx.compose.animation.core.AnimationSpec,kotlin.Any,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1))

You need to use observeAsState() to get the current hour then use an animation on the start and end colors. This will automatically produce an animated state you can use in your gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Hack5's comment I was able to solve my problem and elliminate usage of `observeForever`:

```
@Composable
fun GradientForCurrentTime(viewModel: GradientForCurrentTimeViewModel = viewModel()) {

    val currentHour = viewModel.currentHour.observeAsState(Date().hours) //observing current hour from viewModel as state

    var startColor by remember { mutableStateOf(gradients[currentHour.value][0]) } //remembering start and end colors of target gradient
    var endColor by remember { mutableStateOf(gradients[currentHour.value][1]) }
    startColor = gradients[currentHour.value][0] //actually accepting new values for new hour into start and end colors
    endColor = gradients[currentHour.value][1]

    val startColorAnimate by animateColorAsState(
        targetValue = startColor,
        animationSpec = tween(500, easing = LinearEasing), label = "startColorAnimate"
    ) //animate states 

    val endColorAnimate by animateColorAsState(
        targetValue = endColor,
        animationSpec = tween(500, easing = LinearEasing), label = "endColorAnimate"
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                    listOf(
                        Color(startColorAnimate.value), //using the animate states' values
                        Color(endColorAnimate.value)
                    )
                )
            )
    )
}
```

Comment: If you want to have even cleaner code, you should move the logic that selects the colors in the ViewModel. So instead of having the start and end color like this, you should set the colors in the VM (eg:  `_gradientPair.value = Pair(colorlist[_timer.value / 10], if (_timer.value / 10 == 5) colorlist[0] else colorlist[_timer.value / 10 + 1]` ). Then your view needs only this one as the state `viewModel.gradientPair.collectAsState()`

Comment: @ElizaCamber the only reason why I don't want to do that is because, as I understand, viewModel should have nothing related to the view, while Color is from package `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color`, which is android-specific

Comment: That depends on where you declare your colours rather than where the logic is